# Fail to install software during Debian installation on Virtualbox

Tags: debian, virtualbox, failed-installation

I'm trying to install a Debian Jessie (8.7.1) on a Virtualbox VM.

During the Debian software installation, which correspond to the step after the choice of which software I'm want to install (see screen bellow)
[image]

the installation is getting lock around 27% and then shows a fail screen (see screen bellow)
[image]

When I'm looking at `/var/log/syslog` after having aborted the installation, I can see this
[image]

Apparently, the VM is unable to connect to some hosts.

Is it normal ? Should I ignore this step ?
Do you have some ways to explore? Or some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an internet connection to install the base system. You can install it and then troubleshoot the connection from the Debian terminal. You can install all the packages you need once it is fixed. Try selecting a different repository like http://httpredir.debian.org/. Also check your VM settings to make sure the necessary ports are open and that the network settings are correct. Disable any firewalls.

Comment: The problem isn't about the base system but the software installation which required an internet connection.
So I should ignore and install them if needed after ?
Well, the VM is able to download some software so I guess network & firewalls settings are ok.

Answer (score 35):

For anyone still struggling with this, I finally managed to fix it (albeit on Parrot) by upping the disk size to 32 GB I tried 8GB, 10GB and 20GB but that was apparently not enough! I also tried messing around with many other settings including boot orders and RAM but that was not it either.
Nor was it the ISO in my case but increasing the size to 32 GB worked. Hope this helps.
Don

Comment: This worked for me on debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso.

Comment: This worked for me with debian-10.1.0-amd64-netinst.iso

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me! Somebody please make this the recommended answer!

Comment: This worked for me with debian-10.5.0-amd64. Thank you @datalink

Comment: Insane solution though - especially if you're trying to go small like with debian 9 mini-iso at 39mb and minimum packages.

Comment: Worked on 11.3 with full LUKS encryption and BTRFS, although just in case made it 44.7 GB

Comment: Had to chose 32GB as 8GB got stuck at 0% for debian-11.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso

Comment: On `debian-12.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso`, try 10gb storage and 1gb ram. This combination worked for me (Virtual-Machine-Mangager). I think you'd have to meet "minimum system requirements" @ https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch03s04.en.html

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem on my Windows 10 workstation with Virtualbox failing.

To resolve this I increased the disk size from 8GB to 32GB.

Answer (score 2):

I had almost the exact same problem. However I managed to get one working with a 3GB hard disk by using VHD format instead of virtual boxes VDI format.

Couldn't tell you why this works but hopefully it helps some other people.

Comment: As per StackOverflow guidelines, this content qualifies more as a comment (rather than being posted as an answer).

Answer (score 1):

Just skip tasksel step and go to the grub installation. Later you can install any package you need from a terminal. Worked with 8GB virtual disk

Comment: it didn't help, "volume group nvme0n1 not found"

Answer (score 0):

Tried this install in a Virtualbox VM for testing on win 10 1803. VHD was only 8gb and it failed regardless of installing from the iso only (debian-9.5.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso) or with adding the mirror.  Recreated the VM and increased the VHD to 32Gb and installed from the ISO with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install it on VirtualBox with a 26GB disk (VDI).
I tried to set the VHD with lower values, without success.
Thus, I think that must be a minimum size **around 26GB** for VirtualBox.
Also, try to set **All files in one partition /**, as stated [here](https://superuser.com/a/1159449).

I'm running Debian 10 w/ KDE.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on my Windows 10 workstation with VMWare player.

It is all about disk space. Just increase it from 20 to 40 GB. Done.